# Ajax post parameter always NULL in MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax post parameter always NULL in MVC controller

I have a MVC project, which uses .Net Core.

In one of the shared layout, I have the javascript:

```
var requestData = { term:"myReport" };
var myData = JSON.stringify(requestData);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ReportErrorData", "OperationReport")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#divError2').text(result);
        }
    });
});
```

In the controller, I have

```
public ActionResult ReportErrorData(string term)
{
    var error = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        .....

        error = ex.ToString();
    }
    ....
    var r = new JsonResult(error);
    return r;
}
```

For some reasons, when it reaches the controller, the variable term is always null. However, if I use developer tool, I can see the request body is:

```
{'term':'myReport'}
```

I did the same thing in MVC4 project, and it worked fine. Could this because of .Net Core?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you meant var requestData = { "term": "myReport" }; instead of var requestData = { term:"myReport" }; (note quotes)

Comment: @urlreader It work for meee....    var requestData = { term: "myReport" };
            var myData = JSON.stringify(requestData);$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ReportErrorData", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: myData,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.success);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });

Comment: Note that it can be just `data: requestData,` and delete the `contentType` option (there is no need to stringify the data)